# Use Visual Studio Reportdesigner with Telerik Reporting and MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, telerik-reporting, report-designer

I want to make a telerikreport inside my ASP.NET MVC5 application.

But i also want to use the Visual Studio Report Designer.

All Tutorials are only speaking about using the Telerik Report Designer that generates .trdx files.

How can i use my Reportviewer with the .cs files genereated by the Visual Studio Report Designer?

```
@(Html.TelerikReporting().ReportViewer()
   .Id("reportViewer1")
   .ServiceUrl("/api/reports/")
   .TemplateUrl("/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.htmll")
   .ReportSource(new UriReportSource() { Uri = "Product Catalog.trdx" })
   .ViewMode(ViewModes.INTERACTIVE)
   .ScaleMode(ScaleModes.SPECIFIC)
   .Scale(1.0)
   .PersistSession(false)
   .Deferred()
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

- Visual Studio:

  - Create a new class library or use an existing one. Verify that the targeted .NET framework version is .NET4(+), Full profile as Client profile is not supported.
  - **Right-click** the project context menu and select **Add | New Item | Telerik Report Q2 2015 Wizard** . Enter a name for the report class and click the Add button to close the dialog. Select report wizard form opens.
  - Select the **Band Report Wizard** option from the list and click **OK**.

By the way, did you saw this links:

- http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/quick-start-create-simple-report.html
- http://www.telerik.com/documents/telerikreporting-learningguide.pdf